# Has SETI searched the solar system for life?

Tags: solar-system, radio-astronomy, life, extra-terrestrial, seti

I know SETI is searching the stars for radio signals emitted by advanced alien civilizations, but has SETI searched inside our solar system - particularly moons, planets, and Lagrange points?  I would think Titan, Enceladus, and Europa would be good places to look.  I was talking with GPT-3, and the AI even suggested looking at Earth's Lagrange points to find possible alien probes studying us.  It seems reasonable to me that there could be advanced alien civilizations in our solar system, particularly underground, or in the subsurface oceans.  I think it would at least be worth a look, and we should be able to detect weaker signals at those closer distances.

Comment: Are you specifically referring to the SETI Institute? Or SETI in general?.... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_for_extraterrestrial_intelligence Also, possibly helpful https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraterrestrial_life#Planetary_habitability_in_the_Solar_System

Comment: @Daddy Kropotkin - The SETI institute was what I was thinking of, but I am curious if anyone (even outside of SETI) has looked at these places with good radio equipment to see if there might be another civilization somewhere in our solar system.

Comment: Potentially helpful: [Solar System SETI Using Radio Telescope Arrays](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Solar-System-SETI-Using-Radio-Telescope-Arrays-Cornet-Stride/9e92af2be82d68f72dc96812d5bc3a8273e71971)([PDF](http://www.sunstar-solutions.com/sunstar/Cornet-Stride03/s3eti-ata.pdf))

Answer (score 1):

If you mean SETI search by radio signals, afaik they would have already shown in our records if they came from within the solar system.

If you mean generic search for life, yes, a lot of effort has gone and is going into it for moons and planets of the solar system. I don't know about Lagrange points though, it's a nice idea.